# NodeMailer Response Nothing on Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I use NodeMailer and Gmail API to send email from my server. When I test it on localhost, everything's fine. But when i run it on my server, Nodemailer responses nothing, nothing is sent and I don't know why.
Thanks for reading my question. Please answer, thank you. :'(
Here is my code:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  AuthConfig.clientId,
  AuthConfig.clientSecret,
  'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground'
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: AuthConfig.refreshToken
});

export default class GmailConfig {
  static async createConfig () {
    const tokens = await oauth2Client.getRequestHeaders();
    const accessToken = tokens.Authorization;
    return {
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: 'address@gmail.com',
        clientId: AuthConfig.clientId,
        clientSecret: AuthConfig.clientSecret,
        refreshToken: AuthConfig.refreshToken,
        accessToken
      }
    }
  }
}
async sendMail (receiver, subject, content) {
    try {
      const option = {
        from: 'address',
        to: receiver,
        subject: subject,
        markdown: content
      }

      const mailConfig = await GmailConfig.createConfig();      
      const transporter = emailer.createTransport(mailConfig);
      transporter.use('compile', markdown())       
      await transporter.sendMail(option);
      transporter.close();
      return 'success';
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

idk if you still need help with this but i'm answering :

```
const mailConfig = await GmailConfig.createConfig();      
      const transporter = emailer.createTransport(mailConfig);
      transporter.use('compile', markdown())       
      await transporter.sendMail(option, function (error, info)); // callback here
      console.log(info); // log the body and status etc... 
      transporter.close();
      return 'success';
```

So, basically if you want a response on the server side send a callback returning the response from the sender.